# How to obtain convert DataFrame to specific RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following DataFrame in Spark 2.2:

```
df = 
   v_in   v_out
   123    456
   123    789
   456    789
```

This `df` defines edges of a graph. Each row is a pair of vertices. I want to extract the Array of edges in order to create an `RDD` of edges as follows:

```
val edgeArray = Array(
  Edge(2L, 1L, 0.0),
  Edge(2L, 4L, 0.2),
  Edge(3L, 2L, 0.9),
  Edge(3L, 6L, 0.1),
  Edge(4L, 1L, 0.0),
  Edge(5L, 2L, 0.8),
  Edge(5L, 3L, 0.7),
  Edge(5L, 6L, 0.5)
)

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
                        .appName("ES")
                        .master("local[*]")
                        .getOrCreate()

implicit val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Double]] = sparkContext.parallelize(edgeArray)
```

How can I obtain `edgeArray` of the same structure using `df`? In each Edge, the third value can be any random Double value from 0 to 1.

UPDATE:

I did it in this way, but not sure if this is the most optimal solution:

```
val edgeArray = df.rdd.collect().map(row => Edge(row.get(0).toString.toLong, row.get(1).toString.toLong, 0.0))
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[Double]] = sparkContext.parallelize(edgeArray)
```

I don't like to use `Array`, because I might have millions of edges. Can I pass DataFrame more directly to RDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
val df = Seq((123, 456), (123, 789), (456, 789)).toDF("v_in", "v_out")
```

Import

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.rand
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge
```

and convert:

```
val edgeRDD = df.toDF("srcId", "dstId")
  .withColumn("attr", rand)
  .as[Edge[Double]].rdd
```

With `graphframes`:

```
spark.jars.packages graphframes:graphframes:X.X.X-sparkY.Y-s_Z.ZZ
```

where `X.X.X` is package version, `Y.Y` is Spark version and `Z.ZZ` is Scala version, you can create `Graph` like this:

```
GraphFrame.fromEdges(df.toDF("src", "dst")).toGraphX
```

but it'll use `Row` attributes.