# Creating unipartite graph from bipartite network with GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, rdd, spark-graphx

I'm experimenting Spark and i'm new to Scala and GraphX.

I'm working on a bipartite network of movies and actors who played in them.
My input is a space separated file, with one edge per line, the first column for the movie ID, the second one for the actor ID, here is an extract :

```
movie actor
1 1 
2 1 
2 2 
3 1 
3 3 
3 4 
3 5 
3 6 
3 7 
4 1
```

My goal is to study the relationships between actors. To do so, i wanna create an unipartite graph actor-actor which edges values depending on the number of common movies for those actors.

I start by creating a RDD of edges :

```
val edges: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.textFile("file:///home/actorMovie").map { line =>
    val fields = line.split(" ")
    Edge(fields(0).toLong, fields(1).toLong)
  }
```

Which looks ok :

```
edges.take(10)
res8: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]] = Array(Edge(1,1,null), Edge(2,1,null), Edge(2,2,null), Edge(3,1,null), Edge(3,3,null), Edge(3,4,null), Edge(3,5,null), Edge(3,6,null), Edge(3,7,null), Edge(4,1,null))
```

Then from there, i don't know how to transform it in a weighted unipartite graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have right now is not a bipartite graph. To make it a valid graph you'll have to make a lot of transformations. The easiest way to do it is to use dataframes:

```
val df = spark.read
  .option("delimiter", " ") // if there is a header
  .option("header", "true")
  .csv(path)
  .toDF("movie", "actor")
```

Once you have data self-join and aggregate like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val e = df.alias("df1")
  .join(df.alias("df2"), "movie")
  // Sort soruce and destination
  .groupBy(
     greatest("df1.actor", "df2.actor").as("srcId"), 
     least("df1.actor", "df2.actor").as("dstId"))
  .agg(count("*").as("attr"))
```

This can be converted to `Graph` or `GraphFrame` as I've shown here [How to obtain convert DataFrame to specific RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48079568/8371915).

To create valid graph you'd have to encode labels. For example:

```
val dfe = df.select(
  concat(lit("m"), $"movie").as("movie"),
  concat(lit("a"), $"actor").as("actor"))
```

Then you can apply `StringIndexer` as explained in [How to encode string values into numeric values in Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48082451/8371915) or use [`GraphFrame`](https://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html) to automate this:

```
import graphframes._

val gf = GraphFrame.fromEdges(dfe.toDF("src", "dst"))
```

Then you can use message passing or graph pattern matching to find two hop neighbors.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i still need to analyse some part of it to understand clearly. Why should i encode labels that are already numeric values in order to create a valid graph ? Especially if i have to encode it to numeric values behind ?

Comment: How otherwise, Spark can figure out, that source 1 is not the same as destination 1?